# Argument of type 'awaited T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'

Tags: typescript, generics, asynchronous, types, async-await

I got this error message and don't know what I should do *(As explained in the **EDIT** below I am using TS `version 3.9.0-dev.20200324`)* ...

> error(TS2345): Argument of type 'awaited T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
>     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'awaited T'.

[image: Screen capture of the problem -- Code as text below -- Pop N' Lock Theme by Luxcium ✨]

**TypeScript code: `lib/functional/promise-or-not.ts`**

```js
// ... [more code]

export async function thenified<T>(
  promise: Promise<T>,
  funct: <R>(t: T) => R,
): Promise<any> {
  return promise.then(
    t => funct(t)
  );
}
```

**Output: `tsc Version 3.9.0-dev.20200324`**

```sh
% ❯  tsc # 3.9.0-dev.20200324 
lib/functional/promise-or-not.ts:10:16 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'awaited T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'awaited T'.

10     t => funct(t)
                  ~
Found 1 error.
```

See also [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37664#issuecomment-623716198) in Microsoft/TypeScript/#37664:

> Wrong return type inference in a generic function using Promise.all

#### EDIT

Due to different other problems in my code when using other TS version I am stuck using `Version 3.9.0-dev.20200324`.

This is when using `Version 4.0.0-dev.20200504` other parts of code are not shown here, the problem is detailed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37664).

[image: Many more problems using current version]

[Playground 3.9.0-dev.20200324](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.9.0-dev.20200324&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=57&pc=36#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjThgAtg1DtDgATAHgBUA+ACgCg44woIAtoSTAAXHAAK-ISJasANNxz4MMcYwBKHNXGYBKOAF5WcDYr3ipg4cEYI0KEwG8lUYDFxRSfayIB0FFRcPDzwxsoE7DB6SnoA3JwAvkA)

[Playground Nightly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=Nightly#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjThgAtg1DtDgATAHgBUA+ACgCg44woIAtoSTAAXHAAK-ISJasANNxz4MMcYwBKHNXGYBKOAF5WcDYr3ipg4cEYI0KEwG8lUYDFxRSfayIB0FFRcPDzwxsoE7DB6SnoA3JwAvkA)

[Playground 3.8.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjThgAtg1DtDgATAHgBUA+ACgCg44woIAtoSTAAXHAAK-ISJasANNxz4MMcYwBKHNXGYBKOAF5WcDYr3ipg4cEYI0KEwG8lUYDFxRSfayIB0FFRcPDzwxsoE7DB6SnoA3JwAvkA)

Comment: Seems to work fine in TS v3.8.3 and Nightly: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgIYGcCeA7AxggZgV2zgEsoME4ALEDY3YkAEwB4AVAPgApgEEIYoAW2IoQALgQAFAcNFt2AGh55CWOBOYAlLuoSsAlAgC87BJqX6J0oSJDMkGNKYDeymCDj4Y5fjdEA6KhpuXl5EExUiTjh9ZX0AbmAAX2BgIA)

Comment: @jtbandes you are right due to other problems with awaiting stuff I am stuck with that version of TS (3.9.0-dev.20200324) I have added links to the playground also I don't know is there is a workaround while using this TS version :-(

Comment: Don't use the `3.9.0-dev.20200324` version - switch to the 3.9 beta, if you need to.  The dev version from `20200324` still contains the `awaited` type operator, which meanwhile has been delayed to later TS versions due to some existent [incompatibility issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37198#issuecomment-604160291).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast `t` to `any`

```js
export async function thenified<T>(
  promise: Promise<T>,
  funct: <R>(t: T) => R,
): Promise<any> {
  return promise.then(
    t => funct(t as any)
  );
}
```

Terrible workaround but what can you do.

Comment: Ok I can do `return promise.then(t => funct((t as any) as T));` or I can do `return promise.then(t => funct((t as unknown) as T));`
 


```

Comment: I am not sure the difference between using `unknown`  or `any` in this particular example ...

Comment: It doesnt matter in this case since you explicitly specify output type `Promise<any>`. However when you do `Promise<unknown>` and try to do something later with value it won't allow you (unless you cast it to any).